# When exclude the status flags in the search, the red color isn't applied for the status flags in mobile web

Tags: bug, design, search, mobile-web

In the mobile web search, when searching with any status tag related query, in the result the status-* tag has the red color.

> [user:312043 [status-*]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A312043+%5Bstatus-*%5D)

[image: status-*]

But when exclude the status tag, in the result the status-* tag doesn't contain the red color.

> [user:312043 -[status-*]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A312043+-%5Bstatus-*%5D)

[image: status-* not]

In the desktop view, for the both search results the status tags having the red color.